# Is there a way to globally catch JSON parse errors?

Tags: javascript, json

Either in plain JS or with jQuery is good. I'm already using the $(window).error function, but it only gives the error message "Unexpected token u" on line 1, not any useful line numbers or variable names or what it was trying to parse.

Edit: This is in a Chrome extension.

Comment: That would require editing the source of json2.js directly

Comment: JSON is, happily, a nice *discrete* data format. If you can't parse it, log it somewhere. Then copy and paste it into JSON Lint.

Comment: If you are using Firefox you will get line number also. Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: @techfoobar Why are you talking about json2.js for?

Comment: @Ian - For the OP's need, editing json2.js (and enfocing its use instead of the built-in JSON object) and then overriding the error logging code - is what i meant.

Comment: JSON usually has no linebreaks, so everything *is* line 1 - yet the stacktrace should contain information on where the `JSON.parse` was called. If you want more information on why your file is invalid, try a beautyfier or linter - that shouldn't be solved in the application logic.

Comment: @Quentin How would you log it? The only way I can think of is to do a try catch every time a parse is done, which is not ideal.

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools Net tab? I don't know if it shows extension data or not.

Comment: I'm getting the JSON parse errors from existing logging. Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce it, so I don't know where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a script that patches up the methods found in the `JSON` namespace, and do some custom error trapping there.

Something like this should do. If you use custom a custom JSON library, then place this after it.

```
//sample patch for parse
(function(){

  //store the original parse
  var parse = JSON.parse;

  //patched parse function
  JSON.parse = function(){
    try{
      //try parsing
      return parse.apply(this,arguments);
    } catch(e){
      //something went wrong
      //custom code here
      throw e;
    }
  }

}());
```

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea unless you re-throw `e`. Also you forget to `return` the result :-)

Comment: @Bergi Thankyou! :D Was thinking too much about patching.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work well. Is there any way to get the calling line number as well?